# php count the values between 2 intervals in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following array :

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [serial_number] => 00127B4EE68F
            [start_log_date] => 00:34:28
            [log_date] => 00:36:52
            [good_files] => 11
            [bad_files] => 0
            [interrupted_files] => 0
            [skipped_door_files] => 0
            [max_rate] => 560.52
            [min_rate] => 215.59
            [avg_rate] => 360.54
            [total_bytes_before_transfer] => 40598530
            [total_bytes_after_transfer] => 0
            [firmware] => 10.6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [serial_number] => 00127B4F0F98
            [start_log_date] => 00:59:55
            [log_date] => 01:00:21
            [good_files] => 1
            [bad_files] => 0
            [interrupted_files] => 0
            [skipped_door_files] => 0
            [max_rate] => 
            [min_rate] => 
            [avg_rate] => 
            [total_bytes_before_transfer] => 2276
            [total_bytes_after_transfer] => 0
            [firmware] => 10.6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [serial_number] => 00127B4F0F97
            [start_log_date] => 01:00:59
            [log_date] => 01:01:55
            [good_files] => 4
            [bad_files] => 0
            [interrupted_files] => 0
            [skipped_door_files] => 0
            [max_rate] => 557.7
            [min_rate] => 334.16
            [avg_rate] => 397.21
            [total_bytes_before_transfer] => 11979855
            [total_bytes_after_transfer] => 0
            [firmware] => 10.6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [serial_number] => 00127B4ED82D
            [start_log_date] => 01:08:10
            [log_date] => 01:08:35
            [good_files] => 1
            [bad_files] => 0
            [interrupted_files] => 0
            [skipped_door_files] => 0
            [max_rate] => 
            [min_rate] => 
            [avg_rate] => 
            [total_bytes_before_transfer] => 234
            [total_bytes_after_transfer] => 0
            [firmware] => 10.6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [serial_number] => 00127B4EE61D
            [start_log_date] => 01:54:51
            [log_date] => 01:55:17
            [good_files] => 1
            [bad_files] => 0
            [interrupted_files] => 0
            [skipped_door_files] => 0
            [max_rate] => 
            [min_rate] => 
            [avg_rate] => 
            [total_bytes_before_transfer] => 68136
            [total_bytes_after_transfer] => 0
            [firmware] => 10.6
        )


)
```

I want to check if the value from `log_date` is smaller than the next `start_log_date`. If it's smaller, make a count and continue. I made a `foreach` loop but I don't get the result I want.

This is how I want to display the results (example):

```
Simultaneous connections: 2 - from 03:38:55 PM to 04:51:10 PM - ( 1h 12 min ) 
1   serial number       start_log_date          log_date
2   serial number       start_log_date          log_date
    Simultaneous connections: 1 - from 03:38:55 PM to 03:40:10 PM - ( 1 min ) 
1   serial number       start log date          log_date
etc...
```

This is my initial loop:

```
        $iCount = 1;
    $i = 0;  

    foreach($aRecordsPerDay as $key=>$aRow)
        {

                $aTimeStart[] = strtotime($aRow["start_log_date"]);
                $aTimeStopOld[] = strtotime($sTimeStopOld);

                    if(strtotime($aRow['start_log_date']) < max($aTimeStopOld))
                    {
                      $sTimeStart = $aTimeStart[$i-$iCount];

                      $sTimeStop = $aRow['log_date'];
                      if(strtotime($sTimeStop) < strtotime($sTimeStopOld))
                            $sTimeStop = $sTimeStopOld;
                            $aTimeStop[] = strtotime($sTimeStop);
                            $iCount+=1;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        if($iCount > 1)
                        {
                            echo "Simultaneous connections".$iCount;

                            $iCount = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "Simultaneous connections 1";
                            $iCount = 1; 

                        }
                    }


                $sTimeStartOld=$aRow['start_log_date'];
                $sTimeStopOld=$aRow['log_date'];
                $i++;
                ///show data


                }
```

and this is the result I get:

```
    1   serial number       start_log_date          log_date
    2   serial number       start_log_date          log_date
Simultaneous connections: 2 - from 03:38:55 PM to 04:51:10 PM - ( 1h 12 min ) 

    1   serial number       start log date          log_date
        Simultaneous connections: 1 - from 03:38:55 PM to 03:40:10 PM - ( 1 min ) 
    etc..
```

Comment: Can you show the loop?

Comment: please show attempts so people can help you with problems

Comment: Say your loop looks like this `foreach ($arr as $key=>$value)`, you can easily access the next element now via `$key+1` (if it exists!)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `for` loop with `DateTime` objects:

```
$count = 0; // initialize counter

for ($i=0; $i < count($array) - 1 ; $i++) { 
    $log_date = new DateTime($array[$i]['log_date']);
    $start_log_date = new DateTime($array[$i+1]['start_log_date']);

    if ($log_date < $start_log_date) {
        $count++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
4
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/68557)

Answer (score 0):

Should work if you use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

```
$count = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array) - 1; ++$i) {
    if (strtotime($array[$i]['log_date']) < strtotime($array[$i + 1]['log_date'])) ++$count;
}
```

Comment: @h2ooooooo Made a mistake. It's fixed now.

Answer (score -3):

You can access each item of the array without using a for loop.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $ArrayName.length; $++) {
   if($ArrayName[$i]['log_date'] < $ArrayName[$i+1]['start_log_date']) {
      $count++;
   }
}
```